# Problems with overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

I want to have 5 divs horizontally next to each other spanning the width and height of the window (each div occupies 20% of the window width). Any content that doesn't fit the div should be hidden.
This is how the css looks for two of the divs:

```
#container1 {
    float:left; 
    width:20%; 
    height:100%;
}
#container1 .scrollBox {
    height:100%; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
#container1 .scrollBox .container {
    position:relative; 
    width:94%; 
    float:left;
}
#container1 .scrollBox .content {
    clear:both;
}
#container1 .scrollBox .content p {
    padding:0 5px; 
    margin:10px 0; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size:13px; 
    line-height:20px;
}

#container2 {
    float:left; 
    width:20%; 
    height:90%;
}
#container2 .scrollBox {
    height:100%; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
#container2 .scrollBox .container {
    position:relative; 
    width:94%; 
    float:left;
}
#container2 .scrollBox .content {
    clear:both;
}
#container2 .scrollBox .content p {
    padding:0 5px; 
    margin:10px 0; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size:13px; 
    line-height:20px;
}
```

The containers appear next to each other as I want, but the overflow content is not hidden. The height fits the content...
Any help?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have html,body { margin:0; height:100%; } in your css?

Comment: Didn't have for the html. That did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice, I put it as an answer ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User agents need a reference value to solve percentages. When nothing is specified sometimes the viewport height is used but in most of the case you have to explicit it.

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

`margin` and `padding` rules override some default styles of user agents.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height

Answer (score 0):

Put `overflow:hidden` inside `#container1 {}` instead of `#container1 .scrollBox {}`.